# Cast Page for accessing textbox/object of other page

Tags: c#, wpf, casting, window

Previously, I had only one `xaml`-file, which was the only Windows, namely the `mainWindow`.
To access any button / textbox / object from another class (explicetly a non-static class) I can just cast the Window like this

```
mainWindow mainWin = Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>().FirstOrDefault(w => w is mainWindow) as mainWindow;
```

Now my question is, how does this work for several pages, since now I have a `Frame`, where I load several pages to.
Actually it does **NOT** work like this:

```
myPage page = Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Page>().FirstOrDefault(p => p is myPage) as myPage;
```

There is a runtime-error, which says:

> System.InvalidCastException: Object of type "namespace.mainWindows" cannot be converted to object of type "System.Windows.Controls.Page"

Comment: Page is never in Application.Current.Windows. So you can't find it like that

Comment: but how CAN I find it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This one worked out for me:

**MainWindow**

```
namespace myName
{
    public partial class main : Window
    {
        public main()
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Textbox and Frame, where the page is load into, in the xaml-file of the mainWindow**
Note, the `FieldModifier` is set to `public`!

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox_main" Text="testString main" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
<Frame x:Name="myFrame" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
```

**Page**

```
namespace myName
{
    public partial class myPage : Page
    {
        public myPage()
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Textbox in the xaml-file of the Page**
Note, the `FieldModifier` is set to `public`!

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox_page" Text="testString page" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
```

After that, one is able to access the two textboxes (one directly in the window, one in a page of the window) in any other class via the following commands:

```
// get instance of the main-Window
main mainWin = Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>().FirstOrDefault(w => w is main) as main;
// Access objects of the main-Window
Console.WriteLine(mainWin.textbox_main.Text);

// get instance of the current page of the certain frame
myPage page = (myPage)Application.Current.Windows.OfType<main>().FirstOrDefault().myFrame.Content;
// Access objects of the page
Console.WriteLine(page.textbox_page.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

make MainWindow return a Page, which is displayed:

```
public class mainWindow
{
    public Page GetCurrentPage() 
    {
        // return known Page;
    };
}
```

and then:

```
mainWindow mainWin = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<mainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();

Page p = mainWin?.GetCurrentPage();
```

Comment: nice. how can I return the current page?

Comment: @Pixel_95, only you know which code you have for loading page in mainwindow. you didn't post [mcve] after all

Comment: i load a page via `mainWindow.Content = new myPage();` if you mean that

Comment: (Page)this.Content. and what is the purpose of Frame, if Page is loaded directly into window?